# htaccess Replace all special characters in query string

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like below:
`https://example.com/en/search/result?keys=test"><script>alert('helloworld')</script>`

I need to replace special characters with their respective URL Encodings like below:
& → %26
< → %3C

> → %3E
> ” → %22
> ' → %27
> ( → %28
> ) → %29

So URL will essential become like this:
`https://example.com/en/search/result?keys=test"%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27helloworld%27%29%3C/script%3E`

Is there any way to escape special characters in query string?

I used this to replace tags but all it does is remove the tags.
  `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keys=(.*)("\>)(\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC] RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?keys=%1 [B,L,R]`

Comment: I fail to understand your actual issue ... Why would anyone want to send javascript code in a request?

Comment: Or what actual _problem_ you are trying to fix with this. But I suppose it could be done using https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int

Comment: Could it be that this is _not_ about request rewriting, but about sending out html content? In which you have links and script? If so, then request rewriting is _not_ the right starting point. But either the scripting language in which you create that content (possibly php), or if you have a static setup you could use an online encoder.

Comment: I don't think you should be sending JS to the URL of a browser. But if you are trying to prevent the possibility, possibly trying to secure your app? I'll say focus more on cleaning tne route before it gets to the server.

Comment: This looks like a classic example of a [XSS exploit attempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Exploit_examples)?!